# Scraping a remote URL for bookmarking service without getting blocked

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-domain

I'm using a server-side node.js function to get the text of a URL passed by the browser, to auto-index that url in a bookmarking service. I use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for server-side rendering. BUT I get blocked from popular sites, despite the requests originating from legitimate users.

Is there a way to implement the URL text extraction on the browser side, such that requests would always seem to be coming from a normal distribution of users? How do I get around the cross-site security limitations in the browser? I only need the final DOM-rendered text.

Is a bookmarklet the best solution? When the user wants to bookmark the page,  I just append a form in a bookmarklet and submit the DOM-rendered text in my bookmarklet?

I know SO hates debates, but any guidance on good methods would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want users to submit URL's to your service that grab a rendered copy of the target page into a database? If so, why not only ever get a page once and the next person who requests it triggers an update but add some server code to ensure that there has to be a minimum elapsed time between calls?

Comment: The pages would be different but on the same domain, such as wikipedia articles or Amazon products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do it client-side but I think that would be overly complex. The client would have to send the html to your service & that would require very careful sanitising & might be difficult to control the volume of incoming data.

I would probably simply track the request domains and ensure that I limited the frequency of calls to any single domain. That should be fairly straight forward if using something like Node.JS where you could easily set up any number of background fetch tasks. This would also allow you to fine tune the bandwidth used.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. That's so simple, thank you!